# Cannot connect to internal sites when connected VIA VPN

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, web-server, web-hosting

Our Server (Windows Server 2008) that hosts our VPN is also a web host for our website and our RestService. When on site locally everything connects fine and all sites are accessible. However when you connect via VPN these sites are no longer available but the services on other computers on the same network are (E.G Database server).

Sorry this is a very vague question but any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should check how the hostnames are solved when your are on VPN. Check the DNS resolution with `nslookup` from the VPN client.

Also the VPN configuration might filter out connections coming from the VPN tunnel towards VPN endpoint for security reasons.

Do not use PPTP. It is insecure.